# Migrate Oracle view to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date-arithmetic

I had used this as `Where` Condition in Oracle

```
(ProjectDate between trunc(sysdate-1)+15/24 and trunc(sysdate)+8/24)
```

I was trying to convert view to SQL Server and I used to try

```
ProjectDate between (GetDate()-1)+15/24 and (GetDate())+8/24
```

I am not sure if using right function or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use following expression:

```
ProjectDate between 
                DATEADD(HOUR,15,CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())) - 1) 
            and DATEADD(HOUR,8,CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())))
```

`DATEADD`: The `DATEADD()` function adds a time/date interval to date and then returns the date.

`CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))` returns the same as `TRUNC(SYSDATE)` in oracle

Comment: Thank You very much